# When opening mdDialog, it scrolls down the dialog instead of showing the part on top

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mddialog

You can observe the behavior in this [link](https://codepen.io/KalpanaArivazhagan/pen/XXPwVV). When you click on the button "Comment" it opens the modal, shows the header / title and then scroll down inside the modal.

```
  <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</md-button>
  </md-dialog-actions>
```

I think it is the md-dialog-actions tag, because when I comment it, the modal doesn't scrolls down, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you should include the "focuOnOpen: false" in your showDialog function, just like the following:

```
showDialogDonation() {
    this.dialog = this.$mdDialog.show({
      focusOnOpen: false,
    });
}
```